# The best resolution that a 7 bit A/D convertor with 5 V full scale can achieve is .......mV

Tags: electronics

Can anyone please tell me what should be its answer?

Answer (score 2):

This question is more EE than physics, but with 128 ($2^7$) values, each one is 1/128 of 5V.  But the biggest error possible is when you are halfway between readings.  So assuming there are no other errors like non-linearity of the op-amp, maximum error is 5V/256 or about 19mV.  The resolution is twice that, or 38mV

That's a pretty lousy A/D converter.  An Arduino clone costing \$5 does 10 bits. An Arduino Due clone costing \$15 can do 12 bits at 1Msample/sec.

Comment: [there is an EE SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  depending on the speed, a 7-bit A/D converter might not be soooo bad.  like if the sample rate the converter supports is, say, 10 MHz, a 7-bit converter might be pretty good.  and the way i would define it, i would say the resolution is $2^{-7}$ of full scale and not $2^{-8}$.

Comment: Right, i fixed the resolution which is twice maximum error.